# How to plot the distribution as combo chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Here is my initial data set:

```
data_x <- tribble(
  ~price,     ~id,     ~cost,    ~revenue,
     1,        10,      0.20,        0,      
     2,        20,      0.30,       60,  
     3,        20,      0.30,        0,
     4,        10,      0.20,      100, 
     5,        30,      0.10,       40,
     6,        10,      0.20,        0,
     1,        20,      0.30,       80,
     2 ,       10,      0.20,        0,
     3,        30,      0.10,       20,
     3,        20,      0.30,       40,
)
```

Then, I have a new variable that is zet:

```
data_y <- data_x %>% 
  mutate(zet = cost/revenue) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(., Inf))) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(replace_na(.,0)))
```

Now, I plot the price distribution while showing the zet distribution, as well. Here is my desired plot:

[image]

To do this, I first wanted to see price and zet distribution even they are not percentage now.

```
price_dist <- data_y %>% 
  group_by(priceseg = cut(as.numeric(price), c(0, 1, 3, 5, 6))) %>% 
  summarise(price_n = n_distinct(price)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = priceseg, values_from = price_n)

zet_dist <- data_y %>% 
  group_by(priceseg = cut(as.numeric(price), c(0, 1, 3, 5, 6))) %>% 
  summarise(zet_n = n_distinct(zet)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = priceseg, values_from = zet_n)
```

I would be grateful if you could help me to plot my desired chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d <- data_y %>% 
    group_by(priceseg = cut(as.numeric(price), c(0, 1, 3, 5, 6))) %>% 
    summarise(price_n = n_distinct(price), 
              zet_n = n_distinct(zet)) %>%
    mutate(price_n = 100 * prop.table(price_n),
           zet_n2 = 100 * prop.table(zet_n))
ggplot(d) +
    geom_col(aes(x = priceseg, y = price_n)) +
    geom_line(data = d, mapping = aes(x = priceseg, y = zet_n2, group = 1)) +
    geom_label(data = d, mapping = aes(x = priceseg, y = zet_n2, label = zet_n), nudge_y = 5)
```